# Proper way to adapt an exception with CompletableFuture

Tags: java, exception, java-8, completable-future

I am working on chaining CompletableFuture to adapt an exception.  While I have something that is working, I don't understand why it works.

```
@Test
public void futureExceptionAdapt() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    class SillyException extends Exception { }
    class AdaptedException extends Exception { AdaptedException(SillyException silly) { } }

    CompletableFuture<Integer> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        sleepForThreeSeconds();
        if (true)
            throw new CompletionException(new SillyException());
        return 5;
    })

    .thenApplyAsync(val -> val * 10);

    CompletableFuture<Integer> futureAdaptException = future.exceptionally((t) -> {
        if (t instanceof CompletionException && t.getCause() instanceof SillyException) {
            System.out.println("adapt SillyException to AdaptedException");
            SillyException silly = (SillyException) t.getCause();
            future.obtrudeException(new AdaptedException(silly));
        }
        return null;
    });

    try {
        future.get();
        fail("future should have failed with an exception");
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        assertTrue("got exception: " + getCauseClass(e),
                   e.getCause() instanceof AdaptedException);
    }

    // I am not sure why the above succeeds
    // because I did not call futureAdaptException.get()
    // According to the IDE futureAdaptException is an unused variable at this point

    assertTrue("expect futureAdaptException to have failed with AdaptedException but instead the result is: " + futureAdaptException.get(),
               futureAdaptException.isCompletedExceptionally());
}

private static void sleepForThreeSeconds() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000L);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
}

private static String getCauseClass(Throwable t) {
    if (t.getCause() == null) return "null";
    return t.getCause().getClass().getName();
}
```

First question is why is `futureAdaptException` called when I simply call `future.get()`?

Secondly, is there any way to get `futureAdaptException.get()` to fail with the desired exception? Because I don't want to create a dummy object if I don't have to. You cannot modify `futureAdaptException` from the lambda.

Or maybe there is a better way to adapt exceptions. Or maybe there is a variant of `exceptionally()` that keeps the object in an exception stage (seems the `return null` causes `futureAdaptException` to put the object into normal stage with value `null`).  Or maybe we shouldn't be adapting exceptions in `CompletableFuture`s.

```
    @Test
public void futureStrangeBehaviorFromChaining1() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    CompletableFuture<Integer> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        System.out.println("sleep for 3 seconds then return 5");
        sleepForThreeSeconds();
        return 5;
    });

    future.thenApplyAsync(val -> {
        System.out.println("multiply by 3");
        return val*3;
    });

    sleepForFiveSeconds();

    assertEquals(5, future.get().intValue());

    sleepForFiveSeconds();

    assertEquals(5, future.get().intValue());
}

@Test
public void futureStrangeBehaviorFromChaining2() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    CompletableFuture<Integer> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        System.out.println("sleep for 3 seconds then return 5");
        sleepForThreeSeconds();
        return 5;
    })

    .thenApplyAsync(val -> {
        System.out.println("multiply by 3");
        return val*3;
    });

    sleepForFiveSeconds();

    assertEquals(15, future.get().intValue());

    sleepForFiveSeconds();

    assertEquals(15, future.get().intValue());
}
```

Comment: The new code does not seem related to the original question/issue. It would be better to post this as a separate one, with a specific answerable question. I don't see anything wrong in that code though: these tests should succeed. Remember that each call to a chained method returns a new `CompletableFuture`.

Answer (score 1):

`futureAdaptException` is not “*called*” when you call `future.get()`. What happens is that you created it with `future.exceptionally()` so it will automatically be triggered when `future` completes exceptionally.

So even though `futureAdaptException` is unused (so you could remove the variable), `exceptionally()` still has a side effect.

The `CompletableFuture` that you get from `exceptionally()` will succeed or fail depending on what you do in the passed-in function. If you want it to fail, you can still throw an exception again:

```
CompletableFuture<Integer> futureAdaptException = future.exceptionally((t) -> {
    if (t instanceof CompletionException && t.getCause() instanceof SillyException) {
        System.out.println("adapt SillyException to AdaptedException");
        SillyException silly = (SillyException) t.getCause();
        final AdaptedException ex = new AdaptedException(silly);
        future.obtrudeException(ex);
        throw new CompletionException(ex);
    }
    return null;
});
```

Note that you should probably avoid using `obtrudeException()` as this is non-deterministic. If fact, I am surprised that your first assert succeeds¹. The `CompletableFuture` returned by `exceptionally()` would complete with the same result as the original if it succeeds, so you should work with that one instead.

¹ I definitely think this is due to a bug in the JDK. If you add a `sleepForThreeSeconds()` in `exceptionally()`, the test still passes. However, if you add a sleep for more than 3s before `future.get()` the assert fails and you get the original exception. If you call `get()` before completion, it appears to wait for the `exceptionally()` to execute as well. I have posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44593117/why-calling-get-before-exceptional-completion-waits-for-exceptionally-to-execu?noredirect=1#comment76179753_44593117) to understand this better.

Comment: Now it's is getting very confusing.  I wrote another test that constructs a future through chaining, and another that constructs it through two separate statements and the behavior is different.

future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(sleep for 3 seconds and return 5).thenApplySync(return val*3).  sleep for 5 seconds and future.get() returns 15.  But

future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(sleep for 3 seconds and return 5); future = future.thenApplySync(return val*3).  sleep for 5 seconds and future.get() returns 5.

Comment: @snaran It's difficult to tell from the pseudo code in your comment but you probably made a mistake in your test somewhere…

Comment: Nevermind, I see my mistake.  If you do future = future.thenApplyAsync(...), instead of just future.thenApplyAsync(...), then future.get() does evaluate the chain -- i.e. will return 15 in the example.