# Why calling get() before exceptional completion waits for exceptionally to execute?

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-8, future, completable-future

While answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44578803/proper-way-to-adapt-an-exception-with-completablefuture/44591372#44591372), I noticed a strange behaviour of `CompletableFuture`: if you have a `CompletableFuture cf` and chain a call with `cf.exceptionally()`, calling `cf.get()` appears to behave strangely:

- if you call it before exceptional completion, it waits for the execution of the `exceptionally()` block before returning
- otherwise, it fails immediately by throwing the expected `ExecutionException`

Am I missing something or is this a bug? I am using Oracle JDK 1.8.0_131 on Ubuntu 17.04.

The following code illustrates this phenomenon:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    final CompletableFuture<Object> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        sleep(1000);
        throw new RuntimeException("First");
    }).thenApply(Function.identity());

    future.exceptionally(e -> {
        sleep(1000);
        logDuration(start, "Exceptionally");
        return null;
    });

    final CompletableFuture<Void> futureA = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        try {
            future.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        } finally {
            logDuration(start, "A");
        }
    });

    final CompletableFuture<Void> futureB = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        sleep(1100);
        try {
            future.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        } finally {
            logDuration(start, "B");
        }
    });

    try {
        future.join();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logDuration(start, "Main");
    }

    futureA.join();
    futureB.join();
}

private static void sleep(final int millis) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(millis);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}

private static void logDuration(long start, String who) {
    System.out.println(who + " waited for " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "ms");
}
```

Output:

```
B waited for 1347ms
Exceptionally waited for 2230ms
Main waited for 2230ms
A waited for 2230ms
```

As you can see, `futureB` which sleeps a bit before calling `get()` does not block at all. However, both `futureA` and the main thread wait for `exceptionally()` to complete.

Note that this behaviour does not occur if you remove the `.thenApply(Function.identity())`.

Comment: Seems like `CompletableFuture` does not wait for exceptional to complete when calling `get` after a sleep over the time the exception is thrown. Accroding to JavaDoc it looks like `get` wont necessarily have to wait: "Waits **if necessary for this future to complete**, and then returns its result."

Comment: @tsolakp that is not necessary here though

Comment: Why not? Here is what I think is happening. Thread A calls `get` and since it does not have result yet it waits untill it gets exception and waits again untill it finishes calling exceptionally function before throwing exception back to A. Thread B calls get, since at this time we should already have exception result the `get` will just throw it without again calling exception handler function.

Comment: @tsolakp actually, when future B calls it, the exception handler is still running. What I meant is that it is not necessary to wait for the exception handler to run. It is true that it is necessary to wait, but it waits longer than necessary.

Comment: There is another strange behavior which I've also reported in the other post. If you change the "future.exceptionally(" above to ".exceptionally" and remove the semicolon on the previous line, then the call to future.get() waits for the exceptionally to finish.  It's as if when you create a future through future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(...).thenApplyAsync(...).thenApplyAsync(...), it is different from future = CompletableFuture.supplyAysnc(...); future = future.thenApplyAsync(...); future = future.thenApplyAysnc(...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Waking up a sleeping thread is a dependent action which has to be processed like any other and it has no precedence. On the other hand, a thread polling a `CompletableFuture` when it has been completed already will not be put to sleep, have no need to be woken up, hence, no need to compete with the other dependent actions.

With the following program

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final CompletableFuture<Object> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        waitAndLog("Supplier", null, 1000);
        throw new RuntimeException("First");
    }).thenApply(Function.identity());
    long start = System.nanoTime();

    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> waitAndLog("A", future, 0));

    LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(10));

    future.exceptionally(e -> {
        waitAndLog("Exceptionally", null, 1000);
        return null;
    });

    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> waitAndLog("B", future, 0));
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> waitAndLog("C", future, 1100));

    waitAndLog("Main", future, 0);
    ForkJoinPool.commonPool().awaitQuiescence(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
private static void waitAndLog(String msg, CompletableFuture<?> primary, int sleep) {
    long nanoTime = System.nanoTime();
    Object result;
    try {
        if(sleep>0) Thread.sleep(sleep);
        result = primary!=null? primary.get(): null;
    } catch (InterruptedException|ExecutionException ex) {
        result = ex;
    }
    long millis=TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(System.nanoTime()-nanoTime);
    System.out.println(msg+" waited for "+millis+"ms"+(result!=null? ", got "+result: ""));
}
```

I get,

```
Supplier waited for 993ms
A waited for 993ms, got java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: First
C waited for 1108ms, got java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: First
Exceptionally waited for 998ms
Main waited for 1983ms, got java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: First
B waited for 1984ms, got java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: First
```

on my machine, suggesting that *in this specific* case, the *dependent actions* were executed right in the order they were scheduled, `A` first. Note that I inserted extra waiting time before scheduling `Exceptionally`, which will be the next dependent action. Since `B` runs in a background thread, it is non-deterministic whether it manages to schedule itself before the `Main` thread or not. We could insert another delay before either to enforce an order.

Since `C` polls an already completed future, it can proceed immediately, so its net waiting time is close to the explicitly specified sleeping time.

It must be emphasized that this is only the result of a particular scenario, dependent on implementation details. There is no guaranteed execution order for dependent actions. As you might have noticed yourself, without the `.thenApply(Function.identity())` step, the implementation runs a different code path resulting in a different execution order of the dependent actions.

The dependencies form a tree and the implementation has to traverse it in an efficient manner without risking a stack overflow, hence it has to flatten it in some way and small changes to the shape of the dependency tree may influence the resulting order in a non-intuitive way.

Comment: I was expecting you here for 3 days now... thank you!

Comment: Why when you say to sleep for 1000ms, it sleeps for 993ms?  I was expecting that saying sleep(1000 ms) would make it sleep for at least 1000ms and maybe a few milli or nano second more, but not less.  Does the spec in fact allow this?

Comment: Also, can you please elaborate on your last sentence?  It sounds like in the original program, future is the root of a tree, the thenApply identity is the only child, and exceptionally child of the previous.  This looks like a linked list, and there’s only one way to traverse it.  So not sure why the removal of the Function.identity() node would cause the behavior to change.

Comment: Nice explanation. I guess that's something we'll have to live with :-) In fact, this made me notice that it is not specific to `exceptionally()`: I observe the same behaviour if it is a simple `thenApply()`. I suppose it would be possible to have an implementation that gives more priority to the wake-up actions, however for now it seems we have to rely more on the `*Async()` methods and `thenCompose()` with fast composing functions when intermediate stages are reused (in blocking calls).

Comment: BTW, 2 additional notes: the code given here executes 4 background tasks, so by default on a quad-core the last task will not start before the first one finishes. Concerning `identity()`, I had indeed mentioned it at the end of the question.

Comment: @Didier L: yes, I noticed afterwards that you have mentioned the behavioral dependency to `.thenApply(Function.identity())`. Regarding the 4 background tasks, the ForkJoin pool will start new compensation threads if it knows that a worker thread is waiting, which is the case if you are waiting for another `CompletableFuture`. So `C` is the only task having a wait state without F/J knowing.

Comment: @snaran: in principle, each `CompletableFuture` *can* have an arbitrary number of child nodes (dependent actions), hence, form a tree. Therefore, the algorithm must be capable of traversing a tree. Of course, having just a single chain or a flat list of siblings are special cases of this tree. Considering that notifying a waiting thread is also a dependent action, `exceptionally` is only a sibling of several nodes. But with the `thenApply`, there is also one step down from the initial node before encountering these siblings. Without it, there is only a list (or stack) of siblings.

Comment: Regarding [`Thread.sleep`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-), it says: “*subject to the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers*”…

Comment: On my machine, _C_ only starts after _Supplier_ finishes, and ends at about the same time as _B_ and _Main_. It looks like the common pool does not create any new threads.

Comment: @Didier L: oh right, I forgot that the initial `Supplier` as well as the function passed to `exceptionally` do call `Thread.sleep` as well, so they’re blocking a thread without F/J noticing. There are also some corner cases with small no. of cpu cores. But you may try `CompletableFuture<Object> latch=new CompletableFuture<>(); for(int i=0; i<16; i++) CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> { System.out.println("waiting in "+Thread.currentThread()); latch.join(); System.out.println("wait over"); }); Thread.sleep(2000); latch.complete(null); ForkJoinPool.commonPool().awaitQuiescence(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);`

Comment: @Holger, it is true that in general the execution is a tree.  But in this case it is just a single linked list.  So not sure why the imposition of a middle node (identity here) makes any difference.  Maybe it really is an implementation detail, or maybe it is a bug.